# use fw_printenv for get U-boot's env

Tags: linux, arm, bootloader, busybox, u-boot

I want to use fw_printenv for get U-boot's env.

```
$cat /proc/mtd

mtd0: 00060000 00004000 "bootloader"
mtd1: 00200000 00004000 "kernel"
mtd2: 03c00000 00004000 "root"
```

and

```
$vi /etc/fw_env.config

# Configuration file for fw_(printenv/saveenv) utility.
# Up to two entries are valid, in this case the redundand
# environment sector is assumed present.

# MTD device name       Device offset   Env. size       Flash sector size
/dev/mtd0               0x0000          0x60000         0x4000
```

then

```
$ fw_printenv

Warning: Bad CRC, using default environment
bootcmd=bootp; setenv bootargs root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath} ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off; bootm
bootdelay=5
baudrate=115200
```

would you tell me what's wrong?

thanks a lot. ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it.

```
# MTD device name       Device offset   Env. size       Flash sector size
/dev/mtdblock0               0x40000          0x20000         0x4000
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some background on where these values are coming from?